# CosmosDB with MongoDB API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-.net-driver

Hi I am a newbie on MongoDB and CosmosDB and I try to this in c#

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(
                      new MongoUrl(connectionString)
                    );
                    settings.SslSettings =
                      new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };    
    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
    var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase("MYDATABASE");
    var mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MYCOLLECTION");

    var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;            
    var filter = builder.Lt("mac", "001BC50670101BB8") & builder.Gte("date", "2016-09-18T00:00:00Z") & builder.Gte("date", "2017-09-22T00:00:00Z");

    var query = mongoCollection.Find<BsonDocument>(filter).ToList<BsonDocument>();
```

But when it runs the query on the server I get this error:

```
Errors":["An invalid query has been specified with filters against path(s) that are not range-indexed. Consider adding allow scan header in the request."
```

I have found that I should add the "x-ms-documentdb-query-enable-scan" header to my request. But how I can do this?

Comment: Maybe Mongo dosen't know what is less than 001BC50670101BB8?

Comment: oh... damn. thanks it should be eq and solves the problem

Comment: does it work now?

Comment: yes was the error in the query thanks

Comment: I'll post it as answer so we can close question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found in comment section:

Query changed from

```
builder.Lt("mac", "001BC50670101BB8")
```

to

```
builder.Eq("mac", "001BC50670101BB8")
```